# How to get the parentgroup values in expandable listview

Tags: android

in my expandable listview, my parentview contains two textvies say t1,t2 and my childview contains two buttons say b1,b2.what actually i want is whenever clicking the button b1 i need to get the values of t1 and t2.How can i get this.

Here is my expandable listview adapter

```
public class MyFeedExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

public Context context;
int row;
public List<MyTwitFeedObject> marrayOfList;
public ArrayList<MyTwitFeedObject> feedObject;
public Dialog dialog;

public MyFeedExpAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<MyTwitFeedObject> objects) {

    this.context=context;
    this.row=textViewResourceId;
    this.marrayOfList=objects;

    this.feedObject=new ArrayList<MyTwitFeedObject>();
    this.feedObject.addAll(marrayOfList);


    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView( int groupPosition,  int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Intent i=null;

    ViewHolder1 holder1 = new ViewHolder1();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.woosuite_feedchild, null);

        holder1.b1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        holder1.b2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        holder1.b3 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button3);

holder1.b1.setTag(groupPosition);
holder1.b2.setTag(groupPosition);
holder1.b3.setTag(groupPosition);

        holder1.b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                              

            }                       
        });
        holder1.b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // here i getting the values and storing in singleton varaible but it saying " Cannot refer to a non-final variable groupPosition inside an inner class defined in a different method "

int groupPositionSelected = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString());

                Singleton.screen_name=feedObject.get(groupPositionSelected).getScreen_name();
                System.out.println("Singleton.screen_name "+Singleton.screen_name);
                Singleton.message=feedObject.get(groupPositionSelected).getTwit_message();
                System.out.println("Singleton.message "+Singleton.message);
                Intent i=new Intent(context,Woosuite_NewTask.class);
                context.startActivity(i);               
            }
        });


    //  i.putExtra("name", feedObject.get(childPosition).getScreen_name());
    //  i.putExtra("msg", feedObject.get(childPosition).getTwit_message());


        holder1 = new ViewHolder1();
        convertView.setTag(holder1);
    } else
        holder1 = (ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag();


     ((ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag()).b1.setTag(groupPosition);
     ((ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag()).b2.setTag(groupPosition);
     ((ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag()).b3.setTag(groupPosition);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return marrayOfList.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("gebug in MyTwiterFeedAdapter ");
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(row, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

//  feedObject=marrayOfList.get(groupPosition);

    holder.from_name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    holder.message=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.message_date=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    holder.screen_name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    if(feedObject.get(groupPosition).getTwitfrom_name()!=null){

        holder.from_name.setText(feedObject.get(groupPosition).getTwitfrom_name());
    }

    if(feedObject.get(groupPosition).getScreen_name()!=null){

        holder.screen_name.setText(feedObject.get(groupPosition).getScreen_name());
    }

    if(feedObject.get(groupPosition).getTwit_message()!=null){
        holder.message.setText(feedObject.get(groupPosition).getTwit_message());
    }

                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

public class ViewHolder1 {

    Button b1, b2, b3;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    ImageView profile_img;
    TextView user_name;
    TextView message, from_name, message_date,screen_name;
}
```

}

Here is my logcat

```
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at com.example.woosuite.adapter.MyFeedExpAdapter.getChildView(MyFeedExpAdapter.java:171)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:456)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2011)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1250)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1425)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1143)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4667)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
12-10 15:47:27.429: E/AndroidRuntime(8069):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set tag like following code:

```
    holder1.b1.setTag(groupPosition);
    holder1.b2.setTag(groupPosition);
    holder1.b3.setTag(groupPosition);
```

and in `onClick()` method get that:

```
   int groupPositionSelected = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString());
```

//EDIT

Edit your else with this code

```
   else
   {
     ((ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag()).b1.setTag(groupPosition);
     ((ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag()).b2.setTag(groupPosition);
     ((ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag()).b3.setTag(groupPosition);
     holder = (ViewHolder1) v.getTag();
  }
```

why you call `holder1 = new ViewHolder1();` before setting to your view in if statement? please delete that line and just keep     `convertView.setTag(holder1);`